Failed update to 24.04
I'm new Ubuntu user. 22.04 was first version I ever used. Installed it from bootable stick, all worked fine, managed to fix all the problems with AI and google search while using it. Had it configured great for work, everything worked.
Today I was noticed that there is new Ubuntu release and available for update: 24.04.1 LTS
Tried to update via GUI - failed, I think I only partially upgraded.
Went to terminal and did "update + upgrade", around 300 MB downloaded and installed.
rebooted and Ubuntu loaded, software didn't (ie. vpn client - reinstalled, it worked)
went to terminal, did:
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt --fix-broken install
Another 600 MB of files downloaded (?). Rebooted, it seems like system tells me I'm on 24.04.1 LTS, background changed to black crown (I assume this is 24.04.1 LTS style?)
When I go to "software upgrade" GUI now, it tells me "not all updates can be installed", I have an option to "run a partial upgrade" unfortunately it fails telling me:
"Can not upgrade
An upgrade from 'noble' to 'jammy' is not supported with this tool.
Edit:
@user535733 asked to paste result of sudo apt update:
Tells me 630 packages can be upgraded.

Open a terminal. Run sudo apt update. Please copy/paste the entire output into your question above.

Why there is a prompt on stable 22.04 telling me to update when this is the outcome? -- Ubuntu developers screwed up the upgrade process.

This question is similar to: Major software missing after 24.04.1 LTS upgrade. If the solution in that question does not work, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@user535733 asked to paste result of sudo apt update: Tells me 630 packages can be upgraded. -- That is the last line of the output. Please post the full output.

Don't give up
I had a similar problem with an old desktop computer running Ubuntu 22.04. The upgrade to 24.04 left me with a black screen with a blinking cursor.
Open a virtual terminal
If the desktop GUI is not available open a virtual terminal (What is a virtual terminal for?) by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F2.
I used the following commands:
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo apt full-upgrade
sudo reboot

Then I went back to the virtual terminal and used:
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
sudo reboot

In the Desktop GUI
I was able to get the GUI back after this. I opened the Software Updater app and started a partial upgrade. When the partial upgrade was complete, I rebooted the computer again.
Note the PPAs are disabled as a part of the upgrade process. You can enable the disabled PPAs from the app Software & Updater's Other Software tab. When you enable the disabled PPAs, you will have to replace focal with noble where needed. Some PPAs may not work if they don't have a version for noble (24.04).
Internet or server side problems:
One of the errors you have reported indicate a possibily unrelated problem:
3 Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease
Temporary failure resolving "archive.ubuntu.com"

This indicates one of the three conditions:

The repository server "archive.ubuntu.com" is offline
There is a DNS resolution problem either in your computer or in your router
Your computer does not have Internet connection

The first of these three can happen if the server is overwhelmed with many people trying to upgrade at the same time. Try again later.
If nothing works
Use a different computer to download and create a live installation USB drive for Ubuntu 24.04. Then follow these steps on the problem computer:

Boot the computer using the Live installation USB and select the Try Ubuntu option. Do not select the "Install" option at this stage.
Get an external hard drive and copy the contents of your Home folder in the external hard drive. It is best if the external hard drive has an ext4 partition. This will ensure all the ownership and permissions of the files and folders in the "Home" folder is preserved. However, this is not essential for documents, pictures, etc.
Install Ubuntu erasing everything (assuming you don't have Windows).
Reboot to newly installed Ubuntu 24.04 and copy the files back from
the external hard drive.

Hope this helps

Thank you for your answer. Apparently I missed up. Tried to manually finish updating using various commands ChatGPT suggested. I tried full fist updgrades. Ended up with no access to graphical interface anymore. When I boot to my Ubuntu I see terminal. Here’s the outcome of commands you suggested: https://pastebin.com/3RC6E9Se

"Tried to manually finish updating using various commands ChatGPT suggested."
D'oh
