How to fix system crash loop after 22.04 to 24.04 upgrade
Was logged on to my 22.04.4 system when a dialog popped up asking if I wanted an upgrade to 24.04 noble numbat. 22.04 had been working great for months. The upgrade ran with no obvious errors. The 24.04 system freezes (black screen, unresponsive mouse cursor) as soon as I enter my password to logon. Suspect the OS is crashing and rebooting because the logon prompt re-appears after 15 minutes or so.
System is an HP Omen, 32GB mem, two drives - 256GB SSD & 2TB conventional drive. The SSD contains the obligatory boot partition plus a 250GB+ partition containing the root file system. The conventional drive contains a single 2TB partition and mounts at /home.
Kinda looks like noble numbat is running amok trying to access /home.

press ALT+F2 then follow this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068720/what-can-i-do-to-find-the-crash-reason read the comments and follow the links that is on top.

There are also these  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1525142/failed-update-to-24-04?noredirect=1#comment2682514_1525142 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1524989/major-software-missing-after-24-04-1-lts-upgrade

Never identified the cause of the freeze, but stumbled across a work around. If I wait to logon till the laptop enters power save mode, then logon succeeds almost normally. Almost because for the first several minutes I'm logged on the system is extremely doggy. Top shows CPU usage at between 130% and 150%. Logging on thus has been successful five of five attempts though. Not waiting is unsuccessful umpteen for umpteen.
As an aside, while diddling with this issue I attempted to install 24.04 on another HP Omen laptop with a single 1TB SSD. That attempt consistently hangs at the splash screen requesting my keyboard type - US-English.  Of course I verified the checksum on the downloaded .iso. Tried burning to a different USB drive as well. No joy.
Have a growing suspicion that either Noble Numbat has a distinct prejudice against Hewlett Packard laptops, or the software is not at all ready for prime time.
